# Angle selection motivation for the derivation of the formula for uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why is it that when deriving the formula for uniform circular motion, we chose 2 points, $P_1$ and $P_2$, that are "located symmetrically with respect to the y axis"? Wouldn't this make the derived formula inapplicable to situations where the 2 points on the circular path are at different angles to the y-axis? Since it seems to me that the formula for uniform circular motion depends on our definitions of ${v_1}_x$, ${v_1}_y$, ${v_2}_x$, and ${v_2}_y$, and (I think) their definitions would definitely change if the 2 points on the circular path are at different angles to the y-axis, why don't we need to take that into account?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not good question technique to post a large image of text. You should summarize the details. A diagram to help define the quantities and, in your case, the symmetry idea is okay, but all that text is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points are chosen symmetrically with angles $\pm \theta$ so that you can take the limit as $\theta \to 0$, and obtain the instantaneous acceleration, which is valid for any point on your circle.

The key idea is that you take the limit such that the two points get closer and closer together. It does not matter which points you choose. What matters is that you choose two points, and then "let" them get closer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary for the angles to be symmetric. That simply makes limiting procedure easier to do, with less trigonometric manipulation. The result will be exactly the same. And that procedure is unnecessary if you understand calculus.

One can start with $$\vec{r}= R\left(\hat{i}\cos\omega t+\hat{j}\sin\omega t \right)$$
where $R$ is the constant radius, $\omega$ is the constant angular speed , and $|\vec{v}|=\omega R$.

Take two time derivatives and you have the acceleration vector.